# Правильное представление Model в ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Сразу к примеру.
Допустим у нас есть класс с какими-то данными.

```
public class OrganizationDetails
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Address { get; set; }
}
```

Данные для этого класса мы получаем из файла через другой класс-парсер.

```
public class DocXService
{
    public async Task<OrganizationDetails> ReadAsync(string filePath)
    {
        //Парсим и отдаем результат
        return new OrganizationDetails();
    }
}
```

После парсинга файла я создаю диалоговое окно, где вывожу полученные данные в двух TextBox и пользователь может их изменять. Мне нужно добавить валидацию этого класса и тут начинается мой вопрос.

**Вопрос**: могу ли я сразу унаследовать OrganizationDetails от ReactiveValidationObject(базовый класс для валидации из ReactiveUI) или же мне нужно создать отдельную VM OrganizationDetailsViewModel, где я пропишу все правила валидации.

Вариант 1(делал всегда так):

```
public class OrganizationDetails : ReactiveValidationObject
{
    [Reactive]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Reactive]
    public string Address { get; set; }

    public OrganizationDetails()
    {
        this.ValidationRule(
            x => x.Name,
            x => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x),
            "Требуется");

        this.ValidationRule(
            x => x.Address,
            x => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x),
            "Требуется");
    }
}
```

2 вариант:

```
public class OrganizationDetailsViewModel : ReactiveValidationObject
{
    [Reactive]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Reactive] 
    public string Address { get; set; }

    public OrganizationDetailsViewModel(OrganizationDetails details)
    {
        Name = details.Name;
        Address = details.Address;

        this.ValidationRule(
            x => x.Name,
            x => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x),
            "Требуется");

        this.ValidationRule(
            x => x.Address,
            x => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x),
            "Требуется");
    }
}
```

Comment: "Могу ли я сразу" - ваш проект, ваши правила, вы вправе там делать все, что считаете нужным. "Правильно это?" - нет, ибо вы делаете валидацию всеж UI, а не данных, а за это отвечает либо сразу View, либо если это привязки для UI, то VM. Ну а так, тут вопрос больше "Могу ли я не создавать VM, а использовать сразу Model для привязок?" - ну а на это, хоть и косвенно, вам дали отличный [комментарий](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1566843#comment2824058_1566843).