# Целесообразность использования DTO

Tags: c#

Есть сущность бд **Student**

```
public class Student
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    //Другие свойства
}
```

В каком-либо классе в методе GetStudents я возвращаю коллекцию Student.

**Нужно ли делать отдельный DTO/Poco-класс, если абсолютно все его свойства совпадают? Или же я могу вернуть просто коллекцию Student?**

```
//DTO/Poco класс
public class StudentResponse
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string FirstName { get; set; }
}

//Класс с расширением для конвертацией без использования AutoMapper
public static class StudentExtensions
{
    public static StudentResponse ToResponse(this Student student)
    {
        return new StudentResponse()
        {
            Id = student.Id,
            FirstName = student.FirstName
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: Зависит от "продвинутости" приложения. Если это что-то пятиминутное для себя, то можно и датабазные сущности в API выставить. Если затевается какой-то +/- крупный проект, то лучше сделать отдельный слой DTO, потому что в будущем вам может понадобиться поменять API без изменений в схеме базы данных или наоборот переделать структуру таблиц при неизменном внешнем API. Если у вас будет всего лишь один слой моделей, такое будет провернуть достаточно тяжело, а когда API и бд модели разделены - запросто, нужно будет просто подправить маппинг.

Answer (score 1):

Если брать стандартное приложение, тут используется одна очень хорошая концепция. Припустим, что у вас приложения состоит из трёх "модулей":

- **База данных**
- **Сервисы** (Библиотека либо проект, который занимается
  основной обработкой данных)
- `endpoints`

Теперь посмотрим на логику, как это всё работает с самого верху. Клиент (Клиентское приложение) делает запрос на `endpoint` (Либо взаимодействует как-то с UI, если это desktop). Этот запрос формулируется определённым форматом, что бы уточнить, какие данные нужны клиенту. Для примера, для списка продуктов и для детального просмотра какого-то продукта будут использоваться разные запросы, хотя данные вы хотите получить почти одинаковые. Это всё делается при помощи параметров в `HttpGet` запросе и `headers` данного запроса. Соответственно, используются различные `endpoint`ы.

Далее контроллер, получив запрос, передаст его в **сервисы**. На этом уровне это должно выглядеть буквально как одва-две строки кода. Буквально, вы вызываете метод сервиса и передаёте туда периметр, а потом анализируете ответ сервиса и делаете соответствующий возврат значения (Если это web-api или ему подобный, там может быть Ok, NoContent, NotFound, BadRequest, InternalServerError и так дале) который зависит от результата обработки **сервисов**.

На этом уровне мы приходим к одной очень крутой мысли, что наш `endpoint` общается с сервисами при помощи **моделей**. Хорошо, а что тогда **на уровне сервисов**?

При вызове сервисов мы передаём туда некую модель. В зависимости от этой модели, сервис будет делать **разную выборку** (Это очень важно) в результате какой получит **entity** (Либо список из **entity**). Если что (Я не знаю, на сколько вы глубоко это понимаете, **entity** - это объект базы данных, т.е., уникальная хранящаяся там запись, рекорд и т.д.).

Т.е. тут мы снова понимает, что сервисы общаются с БД при помощи **entity**. То есть буквально, если мы делаем запись в **базу данных**, мы туда закидываем `entity`. Если мы хотим получить что-то из базы данных, мы снова получаем `entity`. И теперь осталось сделать последний элемент в нашей цепочке.

Я уже выше описал, вы `endpoint` общается с **сервисами** при помощи моделей. Исходя отсюда, мы приходим к тому, что для того, что бы мы могли отправить что-то из сервиса на `endpoint` у нас должна быть модель, т.е., та самая DTO.

Теперь, **почему мы должны использовать DTO**? В базе данных хранится так называемая чувствительная информация или **sensetive data**. Получения это информации на клиенте может раскрыть очень много вещей, который вообще по принципу программирования не должны там быть. Это могут быть **Id**, **первичные ключи**, **внешние ключи** и так далее. Для того, что бы такая не случилось, мы используем DTO при описании которой мы сразу исключаем там наличие лишней информации, а записываем туда только то, что нужно `клиенту`.

Вернёмся к примеру с продуктами. При получении списка продуктов, вы будете делать выборку из таблицы продуктов, но вам не нужно полная информация о продукте, вам нужно, условно, только название, цена, там какой-то **shortDescription** и всё. Вы получаете список таких продуктов. Когда вы смотрите конкретно какой-то продукт, вы уже можете посмотреть полную информацию: цену, количество покупок, описание, применение, состав, изготовителя, строг годности и много-много другого. Это всё делается на уровне DTO, когда вы описываете ваш DTO класс согласной той информации, которая вам действительное нужна для описания какой-то страницы (Или эта информация нужна другому сервису)